# creating a binary search tree (manual)

Tags: binary-search-trees

I've been given the following values to add to a binary search tree (in the order given)

56, 35, 55, 58, 29, 15, 16, 5, 71, 92, 69, 95

and this is what my tree ended up like:

but apparently it's wrong?

[image]

Comment: You've edited your question - and it became not clear what you were asking and what was answered... You could keep the original picture and add a modified one. This question and answers might be helpful for others - that's the main purpose of this site, so we all have to think about others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong... The node 29 must be a left child of the node 35, the node 5 must be a left child of the node 15, and the node 69 must be a left child of the node 71 etc. - so, your algorithm makes wrong decision when there is a need to create a left child.

Answer (score 1):

The property that makes a binary tree a binary search tree is that for every branch labeled $x$, all of the labels in the left subtree are smaller than $x$ and all of the labels in the right subtree are greater than $x$.

If you look at your tree, that property is violated in many places. For example, $5$ is in the right subtree of the node labeled $15$, yet $15 \not < 5$.